# Как применить директиву после окончания загрузки данных

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Имеется в HTML коде таблица

```
<div ng-app="simpleApp">
    <div ng-controller="tableController">    
        <table init-table>
            <tr ng-repeat="item in tableItems">
                <td>{{item.Id}}</td>
                <td>{{item.Name}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS код

```
<script src="/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/jquery-datatable.js"></script>
<script src="/angularjs.js"></script>
<script>
    var simpleApp = angular.module("simpleApp",[]);
    simpleApp.controller("tableController", function ($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('/api/Values').success(function (data) {
            $scope.tableItems = JSON.parse(data);
        }); 
    });

    simpleApp.directive('initTable', function () {
        return {
            link: function (scope, elem) {
                elem.DataTable();
            }
    });
</script>
```

Серверный код

```
public IHttpActionResult GetValues()
{
    return Ok(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(db.Values));
}
```

Проблема в том, что данные приходят позже, чем отрисовывается таблица, а нужно, чтобы таблица рисовалась когда в ней уже есть данные. Как это реализовать?

Comment: добавь в свою директиву передачу данных либо флаг, которые ты можешь отслеживать в `$watch` и инициализируй DataTable уже внутри наблюдателя

Comment: второй вариант: если ты не хочешь совсем показывать таблицу - используй ng-if завязанный на данные которые ты получаешь по запросу.

Comment: Второй вариант выглядит проще по реализации как по мне

Comment: @Grundy не сработало :( DataTable все равно не видит в таблице строк, которые ангуляром создаются

Comment: @сергейтамбовцев, значит добавляй больше информации :-) нужен [mcve]

Comment: @Grundy добавил кода, как бы вроде вся инфа, больше нету

Comment: что значит _DataTable все равно не видит в таблице строк, которые ангуляром создаются_? попробуй сделать пример, который можно запустить, например на [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue)

Comment: добавьте чуть больше кода: как, точнее когда происходит запрос на сервер за данными? покажите код контроллера а не только сам запрос

Comment: @Grundy смею предположить что здесь такая же беда как была у меня в виду не умения работать асинхронно :)

Comment: @Bald, не совсем, скорее всего директива initTable отрабатывает раньше чем ng-repeat, в итоге когда вызывается Datatable строк действительно еще нет.

Comment: @Grundy добавил еще больше кода :) Я тоже считаю, что директива срабатывает раньше, потому что сами данные таки в таблицу приходят, но плагин dataTable их не сортирует, потому что работает только со строками таблицы, которые были до его инициализации. Если просто с код написать пару строк в таблицу, то они плагином сортируются, а те строки, которые притаскивает ангуляр чуть попозже уже в сортировку не попадают

Comment: @сергейтамбовцев, серверный код не нужен. Я имел ввиду пример который можно запустить и увидеть описанное поведение.

Comment: @Grundy а не, это я затупил. http://plnkr.co/edit/XvHiq5iP1E94nsDjq7sq?p=preview вот пример, данные в таблице есть, но при этом no data availible

Comment: судя по всему, проще всего будет просто использовать готовую директиву, вроде такой: [angular-datatables](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/welcome)

Comment: в простом случае можно что-то вроде такого: http://plnkr.co/edit/OmCp0prI9a2XUaONRNSI?p=preview но лучше воспользоваться готовой директивой

Comment: @Grundy воспользовался директивой, так даже лучше) Спасибо!